# Where is my regexp fall in jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have got jquery code:

```
$('#register_tab li a').each(function(e){
            var mstr = $(this).html();
            var mre = /<i\>(.*)\<i>/;
            var mnewstr = mstr.replace(mre, "$1", "");
            $(this).html(mnewstr);
        });
```

In mstr strings, like this:

```
<i style="font-size: 25px;" class="fa fa-home"></i> Home
<i style="font-size: 25px;" class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Sitemap
```

I want to see only icons in results, without text, like this:

```
<i style="font-size: 25px;" class="fa fa-home"></i>
<i style="font-size: 25px;" class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>
```

My regexp

```
<i\>(.*)\<i>
```

works good in sublime text, but not works in js, what I am doing wrong?

**UPD:** here is sample code http://jsfiddle.net/28j1tcnm/

Comment: `var mre = /(<i[^>]*><i>).*/ig;`

Comment: @falsetru - thanks, but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex as below.

```
var mnewstr = str.replace(/(<i\b[^>]*>[^<>]*<\/i>).*/g, "$1");
```

```js
var s = '<i style="font-size: 25px;" class="fa fa-home"></i> Home\n<i style="font-size: 25px;" class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Sitemap';
alert(s.replace(/(<i\b[^>]*><\/i>).*/g, "$1"))
```